# Missing value of measure (calculated member )

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I've got a data warehouse which is underlying database of OLAP cube.
When I run query like that:

```
SELECT  dimS.Attribute2,SUM(fact.LastValue)
FROM FactTable fact
JOIN DimS dimS ON fact.DimSKey = DimS.DimSKey
GROUP BY DimSKey.Attribute2
```

I can see that all existing Attribute2 at dimS table have corresponding rows at fact table.

On the other hand I've got a calculated measure:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[MyMeasure]
AS ([Measures].[FactTable - LastValue]
, [DimS].[S Hierarchy].[All].[Hierarchy SomeName]
, [DimS].[Category].[All]
, [DimS].[Question].CurrentMember
, [CimC].[Status].&[Active]
),DISPLAY_FOLDER='Folder',VISIBLE = 1;
```

and when running below MDX:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[MyMeasure] } ON COLUMNS, 
{ ([Survey].[Attribute2].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
FROM [MyCube]
```

I can see that 2 of Attribute2 have no values (null) assigned to them.

What can cause issue like that (DimS and cube has been just processed fully)?

Comment: in your SQL query take a join to the database table of [CimC] and then add active check in the  where filter

Comment: Additional conditions in query against DWH  [CimC].[Status] = 'Active' not impact the query results.

Comment: Try the below query if it returns result for the 2 attribute                                                   select [Measures].[FactTable - LastValue]
on 0,
non empty 
[Survey].[Attribute2].[Attribute2]
on 1
from 
yourcube
where 
[CimC].[Status].&[Active]

Comment: MoazRub thanks for your help. Looks like I have found the reason why I have empty cell for [Attribute2]. Posted more details below.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Found the rootcause.

the reference in MDX definition of calculated measure to  [DimS].[S Hierarchy].[All].[Hierarchy SomeName] is another calculated measure where actually we have hardcoded values within dimension hierarchy. And for [Attribute2] this condition is not met.